# How can I authenticate my MVC5 application through an existing WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating an **ASP.NET MVC 5** application. I have **no access to a database**. Everything I do goes through a **WebApi**.

I want to authenticate users through this API and at the same time get an access token.

How can I do this without throwing away all of the account maintenance code that Visual Studio places in my MVC 5 application?

I thought that this would be in the framework somewhere, but everything I find on the internet seems like a hack. I refuse to hack anything dealing with security. How can I do this?

I'm working with a virgin ASP.NET MVC 5 application. There is no custom code here.

## Clarification:

How can I add a hook into the log-in logic to get the token from the WebApi whenever the user signs in?

## Possible Solution:

I have done the following:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    // Constructor and other code have been hidden to simplify this sample.

    public override async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var status = await base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);

        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiAddress"]);

            var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
            var response = await client.PostAsync("Token", new StringContent(String.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", userName, password), Encoding.UTF8));

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var tokenResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var json = JObject.Parse(tokenResponse);

            var token = json["access_token"].ToString();
            token.ToString();

            HttpContext.Current.Session["AccessToken"] = token;
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

I am going to refactor this code so that this becomes a method call.

If this is a bad idea, please let me know. If there is a better location for this, let me know that as well. I don't like this. It feels like a hack, but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the default template, you authenticate by calling /token with username, password, and grant_type, something like this:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: yoursite.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=something@something.com&password=mypass
```

This should return a token that you can set as a header in your consecutive requests to authenticate your users, something like:

```
GET /api/sms HTTP/1.1
Host: yoursite.com
Authorization: Bearer hegRkzAdXHE-JzAccW-ANpJEyyMU0gBS80ZMxMa1mtpbqGNNtvifMsHVM1O7AinNhIkQuyHbz3wrRcUA0veAC32N8_Oig5f58S6mXiNUbA4y7qLbr4HPyXBQLNq3F29LsnDWJ-cPCivWB13cPeS2en6q39E_ix2CErDDLh-X5i-vmOrK5XgqK1PUlIkyRoA6fvwKKQ3HVrQvNV3D0WSBlIt7i8ykMTnIofAj1_4hpmrQdlLaxq3zfUG9JQbeedUSP5WcjTs1dwdUcJrZWUDrGLHp8bgQ4Av_zx27opx25yyWLOdVsceeth2ytZ0G5vo_m_PCApN9TJGtU70eaYdLa0ZLLIXpG1pDilpGgTeT-bp1qhA8LqKxtXkH54X_o8GlOstoT6NjeyEBG80ZjmHZS_dMn_Uve-qKDGdKPM4JuvBRU2Cqt2M5FiUdGsDjdkOxFVb4xwfAaz0QbwmOAz7xIywIszfEw3blg4eQLefPBAM
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: I know how to do that. I want to know is where to plug that into a virgin ASP.NET MVC application.